PHP Devs and gurus: any idea how to accelerate CRM_Contact_BAO_SavedSearch->getSmartGroupsUsingGroup()?
We have about 2300 groups. When civicrm prepares the modal confirm form to delete a group it checks all smart groups if they may rely on the group to be deleted. It seems that there ist no applicable api4 where clause to exactly get those groups. So all smart groups are fetched and then a array_filter is applied, see lines from
 […]
 foreach ($groups as $group) {
      // Filter out arrays in Form Values which are group searchs.
      $groupSearches = array_filter(
        $group['saved_search_id.form_values'],
        function($v) {
          return ($v[0] == 'group');
        }
      );
 […]

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/blob/master/CRM/Contact/BAO/SavedSearch.php?ref_type=heads#L391
The whole function takes minutes on our site and this filter sometimes takes 1.5 seconds.
I tried everything to optimize this behaviour, read about performance of array_filter, tried different checks in the callback but without luck.
Can anybody with slightly more experience here shed some light on this?

Yeesh, that function isn't even correct anymore, because lots of smart groups these days use api_params instead of form_values.

Okaaayyy, thx Coleman, what can I do? Nay ideas how to easier identify the groups?

It would be helpful to open a ticket on lab.civicrm.org

You're right, I did.

As Coleman commented correctly, this is a case for a ticket.
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5518
